# composer requirements could be resolved to an installable set of packages - zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

Trying to deploy marketplacephp ([marketplacephp.com](http://www.marketplacephp.com)) to localhost.
Composer install is giving me dependencies issues and I've spent hours trying to tweak them so they work to no avail.

Is anyone more experienced able to spot how to fix this please?

P.S. Tried on both windows and ubuntu 14.04 with same results.

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.0-BETA11",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "1.3.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "~2.0",
        "balanced/balanced": "1.*",
        "studio-42/elfinder": "2.*@dev",
        "reliv/elfinder" : "2.0.0-alpha",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "1.5.*"
    }
```

output

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace-dev>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for reliv/elfinder 2.0.0-alpha -> satisfiable by reliv/elfinder[2.0.0-alpha].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.3
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-developer-tools dev-master -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-developer-tools[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.2
    - zendframework/zend-developer-tools dev-master requires zendframework/zend-debug ^2.5 || ^3.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-debug[2.5.0, 2.5.1].
    - don't install zendframework/zend-debug 2.5.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-debug 2.5.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0
    - reliv/elfinder 2.0.0-alpha requires zendframework/zendframework 2.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1
```

Comment: Any reason you want obsolete 2.3 version?

Comment: i bought an open-source application (marketplacephp) that uses it and i'm simply trying to get it to work but the dependencies are screwed.
I've tried up to 3.0.0 and it doesn't work because (I suspect):
zendframework replaces e.g. zend-debug which is used by zend-developer-tools.

Managed to get composer to install by removing zend-developer-tools but I don't know what issues are going to come up from this..

Comment: zend-developer-tools is not compatible with v3 btw. I would recommend you to find all packages used by the application and add them to composer instead of `zendframework/zendframework` metapackage, you can use `^2.3` to allow >=2.3, <3.0

Comment: Also you can ask for help at the new [zendframework slack team](https://zendframework.slack.com)

Comment: oh this is great. If this ends up being suitable, I might end up trying to update it all, so this is all very useful.
Thanks again, Xerkus. Really appreciate it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master"` to `"zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "^1.0"`
`dev-master` is only good for early development time but should not be used long term. In this case current master branch of developer tools have higher minimum requirements than your project supports.

I should note that this set of dependencies hints that software you are trying to install was not updated for around 3 years.

Comment: omg. i've literally been at this for the last 10 hours. this worked perfectly thank you so much!
And yes as the hours went by I realised exactly that this hasn't been updated in ages. Hopefully I take what I can from it.
Thanks again